# Error with import sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

After installing scikit-learn with pip install -U scikit-learn, I'm not able to call import sklearn:

```
>>> import sklearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
  from .base import clone
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 9, in <module>
  from scipy import sparse
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\__init__.py", line 214, in <module>
  from .csr import *
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csr.py", line 13, in <module>
  from ._sparsetools import csr_tocsc, csr_tobsr, csr_count_blocks, \
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

How can I get over this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try using Anaconda to create a virtual environment and then install sklearn via conda rather than pip

https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/
http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/pkgs.html#install-a-package

```
conda create -n yourenvname python=3.5 anaconda
conda install -n yourenvname sklearn
```